# Wikitude - I can't exit world

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, wikitude

I'm using wikitude for my mobile app project. My problem is I cant exit world after click back button.

My code

```
clickedClose: function() {
        document.location = 'architectsdk://actionButton?action=close';
    }
```

I'm using code samples from this repo, https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap-samples

TQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to swipe from left to right or add a button in the Architect World, calling `document.location = 'architectsdk://actionButton?action=close';` as a click action.

Answer (score 1):

Interaction possibilities are very restricted in terms of "back"-button. For technical reason intercepting this event is not same throughout all Android Versions.
As a rule of thumb: Pressing the backbutton on an Android phone will close the AR-View and your're back in your PhoneGap scene.
You may define *additional* actions to this by defining own "backbutton" listener in phoneGap.

In case this does not work for you either I guess you have an Android 4.4 phone in your hands for which we'll soon publish an update to avoid closing the whole app instead of AR-View only.

Technical sidenote: Current implementation of Wikitude PhoneGap plugin spans a fullscreen AR-View right on top of your PhoenGap scene gaining the focus of the app. The backbutton event is intercepted in native Android code to hide & properly destroy the AR scene and returning focus back to your PhoneGap view.
Please keep in mind that the AR-Plugin works in another way than e.g. simple SMS Plugins and may cause troubles in case you are using a cam in your launcher-app too.

Kind regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

This is how I exist from a world:

1. In the world's js file I have a exitWorld function:

   `exitWorld: function(){
           document.location = 'architectsdk://onUrlInvoke';
    }`
2. On the main javascript file before `app.wikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld` I set an invoceCallback:

   `app.wikitudePlugin.setOnUrlInvokeCallback(app.onUrlInvoke);`
3. And this is the close function:

   `onUrlInvoke: function (url) {
      app.wikitudePlugin.close();
   }`

This works really good for me. I hope that this will help you. Good luck ;)